# Web Api 2 MapHttpRoute is not working and is forcing me to use query strings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

Hi I have customs `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` but the API is forcing me to use query string as parameter instead regular parameters separated by / such has this ...api/data/2/23.

If I call my API as `...api/collectdata/1` it does not work but if I call like this it works `...api/collectdata?researchid=1`

This what I have in my WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "CollectDataFromPets",
                routeTemplate: "api/collectdata/{researchid}");
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult CollectData(int researchId)
          {
              try
              {
                  service.SaveDataByResearchId(researchId);
                  return Ok(new { Message = "Data collected and saved" });
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  return new CustomError(e.Message,Request);
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Route order matters. Your generic (`DefaultApi`) route has to be declared last since it's "greedy" - otherwise it will catch all the requests, preventing other routes from kicking in
2. Your specific route doesn't have a controller defined, you will need to modify it to:

   ```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "CollectDataFromPets",
           routeTemplate: "api/collectdata/{researchid}",
           defaults: new {controller = "CollectData"} //or whatever your controller name is
       );
   ```